# How to split before exporting to csv in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, split, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I've this simple script and I'm wondering how can I split WebUrl value, add a new column called "UserID" and add it in there.

Right now it look like this

```
DisplayName      WebUrl
John Smit        http://www.web.com/personal/klmno_gmail_com
```

and I'm trying to add a new column like this after spliting the WebUrl. The URL format will be always consistent. Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
DisplayName      WebUrl                                UserID
John Smit        http://www.web.com/personal/KLMNO_gmail_com    KLMNO
```

```
        $AllSites = Get-MGSite -All
        $odSites = $AllSites |?{$_.Weburl.contains("/personal/")}
        $odSites | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, WebUrl | export-csv $Global:Export -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The `WebUrl` you're showing in question doesnt have a `/personal/` segment, I assume this is just for demo purposes and yours will always have? is the `UserId` always in the last segment of the Url and the first token of the strings delimited by underscore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select-Object accepts a specially formatted hash that can dynamically form new properties on the pipeline object.

This is a quick and dirty example.

```
PS> $odSites | Select-Object DisplayName, WebUrl, @{label="UserID";expression={$_.WebUrl.split('/')[3].split('_')[0]}}

DisplayName WebUrl                             UserID
----------- ------                             ------
John Smit   http://www.web.com/klmno_gmail_com klmno
```

You could also use [Add-Member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-member) -MemberType ScriptProperty

```
PS> $odSites | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptProperty -Name UserID -Value {$this.WebUrl.split('/')[3].split('_')[0]}

PS> $odSites

DisplayName WebUrl                             UserID
----------- ------                             ------
John Smit   http://www.web.com/klmno_gmail_com klmno
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it would be to use a regex expression.

```
PS C:\> $odsites = [PSCustomObject]@{DisplayName = 'John Smit'; WebUrl = 'http://www.web.com/personal/KLMNO_gmail_com'}
PS C:\> $odsites | Select-Object -Property DisplayName,WebUrl,@{n='UserId';e={$_.WebUrl -replace '^.*/(.+?)_.*','$1'}}

DisplayName WebUrl                                      UserId
----------- ------                                      ------
John Smit   http://www.web.com/personal/KLMNO_gmail_com KLMNO
```